# Server Side Sorting for Knockout Grid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I need to allow server side sorting on a knockout grid, I have tried the code below with no luck, any suggestion ??

```
self.sortInfo = ko.observable();
self.sortOnServer = ko.observable(false);
self.sortInfo.subscribe(function (data) {
     self.sortOnServer(!self.sortOnServer());
     if (!self.sortOnServer()) return;
     paginationInfo.SortColumnName = self.sortInfo().column.field;
     if (self.sortInfo().direction === 'desc') {
         paginationInfo.DescendingSort = true;
     } else {
         paginationInfo.DescendingSort = false;
     }
     showLoading();
     self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage(), self.filterOptions.filterText());
});

self.gridOptions = {
        data: self.results,
        enablePaging: true,
        pagingOptions: self.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: self.filterOptions,
        columnDefs: self.columns,
        displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
        rowHeight: 20,
        selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
        jqueryUIDraggable: true,
        useExternalSorting: true,
        sortInfo: self.sortInfo
    };
```

and HTML as below:

```
<div id="grid" class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now sorted, the reason why the code above on its own was not working was because I had to pass the "sortInfo().column" and "sorInfo().direction" values back to the actionMethod that pulls the data from the server everytime the ko grid gets rendered, so basically, once you pass those two values to the relevant action method what you want to do is to use OrderBy<>...  OrderBy<>Descending... using the "sortinfo().column as the key, all of this as part of your server code... so as a result the grid will present the data sorted as expected and for the full set of rows not just those that are currently displayed on screen.